# How can I give players custom names?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

How can I give someone on my Minecraft server a custom name that replaces their own username in that game?

Comment: oh nvm my comment I understand now

Comment: for future reference please don't add `(Minecraft)` or `in Minecraft` in the title, that's what tags are for

Comment: @Penguin Ok, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score -2):

This depends on whether you want to change the name entirely or not. 
If so, then no you cannot. However if you only want to add a prefix or suffix, then yes this is possible. 
In order to do so, you can create a team using `/team create <name>` and then modify the team using `/team modify <name> <prefix/suffix> <text>`. Then add the person to that team using `/team join <name> <player>`. Doing this you can also make the name coloured.

Comment: we dont have teams